# New Relic ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, newrelic

I am trying to use New Relic's .NET Agent in my Web API but all requests are being shown as  `System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler`, which is exactly what the docs [known issues section](https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/new-relic-for-net#known_issues) says

> MVC 4 (Note: New Relic provides limited support for the ASP .NET Web API for MVC4. All Web API transactions will appear as
>   HttpControllerHandler, not as the name of the web API controller.)

I am looking for any workaround that results in a more human readable dashboard, Is there any configuration in my app or IIS that I could change to have a more meaningful metric in my dashboard? Or is there a way of implementing the API calls in order to change this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NewRelic has released an update to the .NET Agent which should solve your problem.

See: https://newrelic.com/docs/releases/dotnet. "Improved WebAPI support. You should now see Web Transactions grouped by [controller].[action] rather than all WebAPI transactions reporting as System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler."

Answer (score 1):

you may get some better results by setting transaction names via the API.  But, until New Relic improves overall support for ASP.NET Web API, there isn't a way to arbitrarily stuff things into web transactions.

https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api
SetTransactionName()

Also, if you specify certain methods to trace, when things are slow and a transaction trace gets generated, you'll see these custom method tracers appear in the trace details tree view.

https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/CustomInstrumentation

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old post but I spent quite a bit of time looking into a similar issue and in my case these delays were only appearing during POST where http message had request content.

In the long run, this was due to network performance problems (mobile clients) and the POST was trying to read the body of the message which is taking a long time to transmit.  The take away being that these delays while showing in the controller handler were actually just waiting for the request body to be transmitted.